# wildcard type matching - Java

Tags: java, generics

Why won't the following code compile?

```
public static <T> void foo_test(List<? extends T> src, List<T> dest) {
   for (T o : src) {
        dest.add(o);
   }
}

public static void main(String [] args) {
   List<Number> numbers = new ArrayList<Number>();
   List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   foo_test(numbers, integers);
}
```

Comment: Because `Number` does not extend `Integer`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't and can't add the list of numbers to a list of integers; the numbers may not be integers.  However, you can add a list of integers to a list of numbers, the backwards of what you've typed.

This will work:

```
foo_test(integers, numbers);
```

To elaborate, `T` is inferred as `Integer` in your code, but `Number` doesn't extend `Integer`, so the call is a compiler error.

Switching to `foo_test(integers, numbers)` makes `T` inferred as `Number`, and `Integer` does extend `Number`, so that compiles.

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch `integers` and `numbers`. The `src` list has to be the more specific type than `dest`.